# Why does HtmlParser remove the line break tags?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm using this [HtmlFromXamlConverter](https://github.com/microsoft/WPF-Samples/blob/master/Sample%20Applications/HtmlToXamlDemo/HtmlFromXamlConverter.cs) from Microsoft and trying to display html script on a RichTextBox.
HtmlToXamlConverter is working fine but HtmlFromXamlConverter isn't.

Example:

```
#Part.143
<p><b><font size="5">Wundklassifikation Diabetisches Fußsyndrom nach Wagner</font></b></p>
<b>Grad 0</b><br>Keine Läsion, evtl. Fußdeformation oder Cellulitis<br><br>
<b>Grad 1</b><br>Oberflächliches Ulkus<br><br>
<b>Grad 2</b><br>Tiefes Ulkus bis zur Gelenkkapel<br><br>
<b>Grad 3</b><br>Tiefes Ulkus mit Abszedierung, Osteomyelitis, Infektion der Gelenkkapsel<br><br>
<b>Grad 4</b><br>Begrenzte Vorfuß- oder Fersennekrose<br><br>
<b>Grad 5</b><br>Nekrose des gesamten Fußes<br><br>
```

If I convert this html script to XAML script using the [HtmlToXamlConverter](https://github.com/microsoft/WPF-Samples/blob/master/Sample%20Applications/HtmlToXamlDemo/HtmlToXamlConverter.cs), it is shown on the RichTextBox as follows:
[Screenshot from RichTextBox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4gUJ.png)

And then when I convert it back from XAML to html using [HtmlFromXamlConverter](https://github.com/microsoft/WPF-Samples/blob/master/Sample%20Applications/HtmlToXamlDemo/HtmlFromXamlConverter.cs) and use the generated html code to display it on RichTextBox, it is shown on the RichTextBox as follows:
[Screenshot from RichTextBox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6UK3.png) (line breaks are no longer included)

This is the c# code that I use to convert from and to XAML

Convert from html to Xaml:

```
if(XamlReader.Parse(HtmlToXamlConverter.ConvertHtmlToXaml(File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\XXX\Documents\testHtml.html"), true)) is FlowDocument flowDoc)
{
           
      RichTextBox.Document = flowDoc;
}
```

Convert back from Xaml to html:

```
string str1 = XamlWriter.Save(RichTextBox.Document);
string str = XamlToHtmlConverter.ConvertXamlToHtml(str1);
```

I have been trying for a long time and no success. I am grateful for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is a case of the converters not being symmetrical.

Try this:

- Find in Files (*Ctrl-Shift-F* on Visual Studio), and search for `"Paragraph"`. You'll see that it has matches in both **ToXaml** and **FromXaml**. They are responsible for converting `<p>` to `<Paragraph>` and vice versa.
- Now look for `"LineBreak"`. This is the cause of your issue; it only exists in **ToXaml** but not the other way around.

The solution is simply to add a LineBreak handler in **HtmlFromXamlConverter**. Just add it next to the Paragraph handler.

```
case "Paragraph":
    htmlElementName = "p";
    break;
// Add these:
case "LineBreak":
    htmlElementName = "br";
    break;
```

That should do it.

NOTE: I hope you're not using `<hr>` cause that's another one that wouldn't work, and will be harder to fix.